# How to use python variable in javascript getElementById()?

Tags: javascript, python

I want to pass python variable in to javascript. The variable value is an element id and so I want to pass this variable having element id to javascript "getElementById"

I tried -

```
element = 'id_of_element'

js = """
var element = document.getElementById(""" + element + """)
"""
```

But I get error - WebDriverException: Message: u'element is null'. Please advise. I am newbee to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution -

You have to use a single quote around around the three double quotes

Like this  -

```
element = 'id_of_element'
js = """
var element = document.getElementById('"""+element+"""')
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) :

```
element = 'id_of_element'

js = """
var element = document.getElementById("{}")
""".format(element)
```

Comment: It's giving me error - var element = document.getElementById("""{element}""");
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax