# Display python variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, cgi

I have a website using python and cgi.  The website currently runs a python script watching for changes in logic lines and prints the data to the website as new data comes in. This works fine.
What I need is a way to remove the old data and replace it with new data. I have read that it is easy to update a div tag with some javascript.  However, I have only seen examples with a certain amount of time has passed or when a button is clicked. Neither of these are options for what I am doing.  I do not know javascript.

I see this link, but without any context, it means nothing to me.   [How to use python variable in javascript getElementById()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26683501/how-to-use-python-variable-in-javascript-getelementbyid)

How can I accomplish this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Time to learn JavaScript.

Comment: Where is the Python variable coming from? Is it on the page already as an id/value/text? Is being sent periodically from the server? Are you pulling it from the server with an AJAX request? Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Script1.py is the website, it calls Script2.py.  Script2 only uses python to get the information and then prints the text and values.   The information is sent whenever the information changes.
No AJAX or jQuery

Answer (score 0):

So I found this workaround.  I do not really like it.
I create a text variable with javascript code in it and the number that needs to update.  Then I print that line.  As the number updates, I reprint that text variable.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import cgi
import time
import sys
import json

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
#<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5'>
print """
<head></head>
<body>
    <p id='p'> </p>
"""
num = 19
#js = "<script>document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = " + str(num) + "; </script>"
js = "<script>document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = " + json.dumps(num) + "; </script>"
print js
sys.stdout.flush()
while num < 22:
    num += 1
    time.sleep(1)
    #js = "<script>document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = " + str(num) + "; </script>"
    js = "<script>document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = " + json.dumps(num) + "; </script>"  
    print js
    sys.stdout.flush()

print"""

</body>
</html>
 """
```

Comment: You  should be encoding as JSON instead of using `str()` to generate JavaScript literals.

Comment: Thank you.  That makes the formatting a lot easier to handle.